# Sending special/region specific characters during form submit

Tags: java, html, jsp, encoding, struts

I have a form, which will be submitted to Struts Action and will get processed and returns output.

However the input data has special characters like "Louvière", if users submits the form, In the back end, Struts fetching this value as "La Louvi�re".

How do i handle this situation as the input should accept specially Euro characters.

in the jsp page header I am encoding as

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

and form defined like

```
<s:form id="myform" action="myAction" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the encoding equals the encoding of the document containing the `<form>` element. Hence, either change the charset instruction of the document containing the `<form>` like so

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Or add the `accept-charset` attribute to the form element like so:

```
<s:form id="myform" action="myAction" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The browser should then use the declared charset when submitting the POST request.

Sidenote, the Euro symbol (€) is not part of iso-8859-1 but of iso-8859-15.

Comment: Tried. still ? is getting submitted [using iso-8859-15]. if I use utf-8 i am getting ? instead of è in view itself, i need to show it as è and if user searches something by submitting è, it should accept exactly.


Could it be an issue with Spring/struts also?

Comment: @NitinGurram, "if I use utf-8 i am getting ? instead of è in view itself" - you seem to have more than one encoding issue. If you see ? instead of è this most likely means that the server is actually sending latin1 (iso-8859-1) but if you set `<meta....charset=utf-8">` you tell the browser to interpret it as utf-8 which is obviously wrong. So, don't mess with the `<meta>`. When _reading_ values from the request Struts depends upon the charset set by the browser when it submitted it. Sometimes browsers don't set one at all.

Comment: @NitinGurram, you can support the server in detecting which charset to use (if it's not in the request) e.g. with Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter` http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html. For even more information see http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8.

Comment: I tried changing server.xml as per the documentation. still the problem persists.